# Why do the predicates for find() and position() require different types?

Tags: rust

Given the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    // find the first element > 3
    println!("{}", vec.iter().find(|&x| *x > 3).unwrap());
    // find the position of the first element > 3
    println!("{}", vec.iter().position(|&x| x > 3).unwrap());
}
```

and looking at the docs:

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item>

fn position<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<usize>
```

I find it hard to understand why `find()` needs the `*x` and `position()` needs just `x`. Both have `&mut self` and it looks to me as if both do the same work in the predicate.

I guess this can be deduced by the different return types, but what is the exact rule with that?

Comment: Also note that the docs currently don't show the required traits for the predicate. For `find` it is `P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool` and for `position` it is `P: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool`.

Comment: Well this means you can't deduce it from the docs and need to "experiment" or look at the source of the methods. Thats just bad in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed! It's a bug in the doc generation, and is tracked in [20534](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20534) or maybe [20203](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20203).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try it out!

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyNum(u8);

trait MyExt: Iterator + Sized {
    fn my_find<P>(&mut self, mut predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item>
    // Changed to take the item directly, not a reference
    where
        P: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool,
    {
        for x in *self {
            if predicate(x) {
                return Some(x);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

impl<I> MyExt for I
where
    I: Iterator,
{
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let vec: Vec<MyNum> = vec.drain(..).map(|x| MyNum(x)).collect();
    // find the first element > 3
    println!("{:?}", vec.iter().my_find(|x| x.0 > 3).unwrap());
}
```

This compiles with the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:10:18
   |
10 |         for x in *self {
   |                  ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:12:29
   |
11 |             if predicate(x) {
   |                          - value moved here
12 |                 return Some(x);
   |                             ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

The problem is that we can iterate over **non-copyable values**. When we use `position`, we don't need the value after calling the predicate, so it's safe to just pass the value in, consuming it in the process. When we call `find`, however, we need to pass the value to the predicate and *then* pass it as the return value. This means that the predicate must not consume the value!

Comment: This explains the why. I am not satisfied. But thats not your fault I guess.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm very happy that Rust ensures that I don't use use a value after it's been moved! ^_^ I could see two solutions to unify the problems: Both could take a reference, or there could be a `find_copyable` that has an additional `T: Copy` bound. Neither seem that great to me.